# Script output in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code:

```
app.get('/scr', function(req, res) {
    var command = spawn(scripts + "/script.sh");
    command.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

The script outputs `Hello World!`. I would like to have this output on my browser when going to `http://localhost:XXXX/scr`. However, this wants me to download a file with `Hello World!` inside. How can I obtain that output on my browser?

Comment: where is your browser code?

Comment: @lombausch: Probably [here](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip) or [here](https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/). More seriously, I think they’re asking a purely server-side question; the only part of the question related to the client was why the browser was prompting them to download it rather than just view it.

Answer (score 2):

It’s likely that the `data` event will be fired multiple times, but `send` can only be called once. Rather than using `send`, use `write` and `end`; or, since `command.stdout` is a stream, just pipe it into the response:

```
command.stdout.pipe(res);
```

You may want to explicitly set the MIME type before that, though, e.g.:

```
res.type('text/plain');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a content type.

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```